# Extract text with bold content from css selector

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, css-selectors, scrapy

I am trying to extract a text from forum posts, however the bold element is ignored.

How can I extract raw data like `Some text to extract bold content?` Currently I am getting only `Some text to extract ?`

```
<blockquote class="messageText SelectQuoteContainer ugc baseHtml">
Some text to extract <b>bold content</b>?
</blockquote>
```

---

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('article'):
        yield {
            'text': quote.css('blockquote::text').extract()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a space in your css selector:

```
'blockquote ::text'
           ^
```

Because you want `text` of every descending node under blockquote, without space it means just the text of blockquote node.

Comment: The not selector will stop working with the space? `blockquote:not(.bbCodeBlock) ::text`  Apparently yes.

Comment: @anvd just tested, it should and does works fine. Tested: `'blockquote:not(.foo) ::text'`

Comment: the markup is a bit more complicated, and it will not work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/dwfmLcaj/

Comment: @anvd This is not javascript. Scrapy converts all css selectors to xpath so the only css selector implementation that matters here is `cssselect` package, see: https://github.com/scrapy/cssselect.

Comment: thanks for the link, but currently the problem is the css. I don't even know how select that part of text that don't have any element associated. The problem is css for now

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` selector to select text of all inner elements inside an element.

`''.join([ a.strip() for a in quote.css('blockquote *::text').extract() ])`